# Download file returns 403 in Linux machine, but works in Windows

Tags: node.js

The download fails with `wget` and `curl` but the actual code I use to download is this:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import axios from "axios";

export async function downloadFile(url: string, destPath: string) {
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(destPath);

  const response = await axios({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "stream",
    // this "httpsAgent" used to be needed, but now doesn't work regardless
    //httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    //  rejectUnauthorized: false,
    //}),
  });

  response.data.pipe(writer);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on("finish", resolve);
    writer.on("error", reject);
  });
}
```

When running on my Windows 10 machine it works just fine, but on the production machine it return `403`
Below in an example file with random data I generated:

```
root@le-machine [~]# wget https://boletoonline.caixa.gov.br/ecobranca/SIGCB/imprimir/1150229/14000000139489640
--2022-10-06 15:48:23--  https://boletoonline.caixa.gov.br/ecobranca/SIGCB/imprimir/1150229/14000000139489640
Resolving boletoonline.caixa.gov.br (boletoonline.caixa.gov.br)... 206.41.74.19
Connecting to boletoonline.caixa.gov.br (boletoonline.caixa.gov.br)|206.41.74.19|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2022-10-06 15:48:27 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

It used to work, but one day it stopped, I tried defining some headers to make it look like it's a browser to see if that helps, but that doesn't seem to be the issue, since in my machine it works just fine.

I assume it's some problem with SSL, TSL, certificate or something the like... but no idea.

Edit:

Printing the error returned from axios gives me these headers:

```
response: {
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: {
      server: 'azion webserver',
      date: 'Fri, 07 Oct 2022 04:23:41 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close'
    },

...

request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
  _events: [Object: null prototype],
  _eventsCount: 7,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  _closed: false,
  socket: [TLSSocket],
  _header: 'GET /ecobranca/SIGCB/imprimir/1150229/14000000138314020 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
    'Host: boletoonline.caixa.gov.br\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
```

ad

The file with the complete success response and the error response objects: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YPb7NLwfs_ZwuCa3DJLb7ZeWk9CvbqJT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Post your Request & Response headers. For both: linux & windows, and edit your question please to the information i requested.

Comment: Please use `err.toJSON()` to display the Axios error. See https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Comment: @Marc I appended `err.toJSON()` to the end of the file in Google Drive, but it just displays the same thing with a lot less information